# Why is $\sigma(X_i) = \{ (X_i \in A) \ | \ A \in \mathbb{B}\}$

Tags: measure-theory

Why is $$\sigma(X) = \{ (X \in A) \ | \ A \in \mathbb{B}\}$$
where $X$ is a random variable.

Shouldn't it be $$\sigma(X) = \sigma(\{ (X \in A) \ | \ A \in \mathbb{B}\} )$$

or is $\{ (X \in A) \ | \ A \in \mathbb{B}\}$ already a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Indeed, $\{ (X \in A) \ | \ A \in \mathbb{B}\}$ is already a $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 0):

$\{(X\in A) | A\in \mathbb{B} \}$ is already a $\sigma$-algebra.
It is clear that it is the smallest such $\sigma$-algebra because it only contains the pre-images of $A\in \mathbb{B}$, which are necessary for X to be measurable.